# Using vector iterator in function prototype

Tags: c++, function, iterator, prototype

I want to do the following:

```
vector<int> vec;    
auto iter = vec.begin();
```

Now I want a function which takes iter as an input and returns iter.

```
____ func(___ & iter)
```

where `___` is to be filled in. What should `___` be?

Comment: If you read any pre-C++11 tutorial, you will see plenty of places where iterators are declared, most notably in `for` loops. Declaring a loop iterator or an iterator function argument/return type doesn't matter, it's still done the same way.

Comment: Reading a [good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) should help as well.

Comment: Alternatively, do as just about any [standard algorithm function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) does, and use templates.

Comment: Thank you. Please bear with us beginners, as questions that appear trivial to experts may take beginners a long time to figure out even if we read the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit silly example, but here is some examples of using templates and decltype to deduce type of iterators:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;

template <class T> void double_vals(T vbeg, T vend)
{
    for (; vbeg != vend; ++vbeg)
        *vbeg *= 2;
}

template <class T, class T2> auto find_val(T vbeg, T vend, T2 val) -> decltype(vbeg)
{
    for (; vbeg != vend; ++vbeg)
        if (*vbeg == val) return vbeg;

    return vbeg;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec = {10, 20, 30};

    auto it1 = vec.begin();
    auto it2 = vec.end();

    double_vals(it1, it2);
    auto it3 = find_val(it1, it2, 20);
    if (it3 != vec.end())
        cout << "Found value!\n";

    for (auto i : vec)
    {
        cout << i << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}

// Note that you could avoid using decltype() here by doing 
template <class T, class T2> T find_val(T vbeg, T vend, T2 val)
{
    for (; vbeg != vend; ++vbeg)
        if (*vbeg == val) return vbeg;

    return vbeg;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Erik. This is not silly at all, an example can be very helpful for beginners like myself.

Comment: Note also that decltype is necessary if e.g. you have a template function taking two different templated types as arguments and returning e.g. the sum of two variables of the two types. Then you may use decltype for the return value (the sum).

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector<int>::begin()` returns an instance of type `std::vector<int>::iterator`, or `std::vector<int>::const_iterator` if the callee is marked `const`.

In your example, `decltype(iter)` will be `std::vector<int>::iterator`, so just declare the function like so:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator
func (std::vector<int>::iterator iter);
```

Note that STL iterators are designed to be passed by value, so I got rid of the reference in the function signature.

Answer (score 0):

That actually depends on the iterator type you need. In general it will be `vector<int>::iterator`.
`begin()` is defined as:

```
iterator begin() noexcept;
const_iterator begin() const noexcept;
```